# Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal in access

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Private Sub SupplierID_AfterUpdate()
On Error GoTo errHandler

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset



    ID = IIf(IsNull(DMax("ID", "PurchaseOrders")) = True, 1, DMax("ID", "PurchaseOrders") + 1)
    OrderDate = Date
    'saveFlag = False

    CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM tempOrders", dbFailOnError


    rs.Open "SELECT ([Products.PRCODE]), ([ProductsPriceList.SID]), ([Products.PRODUCT]), ([Products.SIZE]), ([Products.PACK]), ([ProductsPriceList.PRICE]) FROM Products INNER JOIN ProductsPriceList ON Products.PRCODE = ProductsPriceList.PRCODE  ", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

    While rs.EOF = False

        Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

        With cmd
            .ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
            .CommandType = adCmdText

                .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("p1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, rs.Fields("PRCODE"))
                .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("p2", adInteger, adParamInput, 10, rs.Fields("SID"))
                .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("p3", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, rs.Fields("PRODUCT"))
                .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("p4", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, rs.Fields("SIZE"))
                .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("p5", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, rs.Fields("PACK"))
                .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("p6", adCurrency, adParamInput, 10, rs.Fields("PRICE"))

                strSQL = "INSERT INTO tempOrders(PRCODE, SID, PRODUCT,SIZE,PACK,PRICE) VALUES(p1, p2,P3,P4,P5, p6)"





            .CommandText = strSQL
            .Execute
        End With
        Set cmd = Nothing





        rs.MoveNext
    Wend
    rs.Close

    Set rs = Nothing

    PurchaseOrders_subform.Form.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM tempOrders ORDER BY PRODUCT"
```

The above code has given the error of "Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal in access"

Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

In your Select-SQL you enclose the table name and the column name in square brackets. - This is incorrect and I am surprised that queries does not return an error in right away.

That results in the fields created from the query being named Tablename.Columnname in the recordset.So you either need to refer to the fields by those names

```
... rs.Fields("Products.PRCODE") ...
```

or you correct the Select-SQL. That's what I would recommend!

The correct way to reference the fields in the query is to enclose the individual identifiers in square brackets.

```
SELECT [Products].[PRCODE], [ProductsPriceList].[SID], ... FROM Products
```